# getting dictionary item out of nsmutablearray swift3 playground

Tags: swift, dictionary, swift3, nsmutablearray

I was trying to get this to work based off of this video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CFtffLlgMNs

This cell-line doesn't seem to work for Swift 3:

```
cell.textLabel?.text = "\(client.objectForKey("firstName")!)"
```

How do I retrieve "lastName" of index[0] out of this NSMutableArray?
Or should I be using a different method?

```
var dictClients = [String:String]()
var arrayClients = NSMutableArray()

dictClients["firstName"] = "john"
dictClients["lastName"] = "smith"

arrayClients.add(dictClients)

dictClients["firstName"] = "pocahontas"
dictClients["lastName"] = "smith"

arrayClients.add(dictClients)
```

Comment: Why are you using `NSMutableArray` instead of a Swift array?

Comment: you don't have an object named `client`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all don't use NSMutableArray in Swift, use Array.
So make `var arrayClients = [[String:String]]()`
Then you can access the property as `arrayClients.first?["lastName"]` for the element with index 0.